# Calling a function from a module on a submodule

Tags: python, module, python-import

I'm quite new to working with more complex modules, but I think is about time to implement them in my work flow. Also, I don't come from a software engineering background so some of my languages might be inaccurate, please bear with me. My module folder structure is like this:

```
+-- module_name
|   +-- ml.py
|   +-- exp_an.py
|   +-- plotting.py
+-- etl
|   +-- machine_learning.py
|   +-- data_manipulation.py
```

The reason I have two folders is because the scripts directly on `module_name` are our personal library for use on most projects and the `etl` has code that is specific to this project.

In the beginning I had both folders on the same directory but I was having trouble importing from `module_name` to `etl`.

The thing is, in `machine_learning.py` I want to call a function from `ml.py`. I tried doing:

```
import sys
sys.append('../')
import module_name as mn
```

But this seems to bring some recursivity issues, because when I try to call mn.ml I get a `mn has no attribute called ml` error.

So, my question is, what is the right way to do this? Let's say I want to call a function called `transform()` that is inside `ml.py` in my `machine_learning.py` script. Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `sys.append('../')` That is the parent of _the current working directory_, not the parent of the directory that _this module was imported from_.

Comment: How to call a _what_?

Answer (score 2):

In order for your directories to be interpreted as modules, you need to add __init__.py in each directory. Your directory structure will look like this.

```
+-- module_name
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- ml.py
|   +-- exp_an.py
|   +-- plotting.py
+-- etl
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- machine_learning.py
|   +-- data_manipulation.py
```

Then you'd use relative imports to get the modules. Example ->

```
# Inside machine_learning.py you are importing ml.py
import ..ml as ml

ml.transform()
```

Here is an example of a larger project. You can see how relative imports are used and the directories have their __init__.py.

https://github.com/TileThePlane/docusign-python-client

Comment: Python 3 doesn't require `__init__.py`.

Comment: But  is `__init__.py` needed to use relative imports?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add the parent directory of `module_name` and `etl` (whatever that directory is) to your `PYTHONPATH`.

After doing that, you should be able to do all the imports you asked for.

To explain the `mn has no attribute called ml` error, that happened because you did not *import* `ml`.  You just tried to use it as an attribute of `mn`, and you can't do that.

Comment: Why can't I use `ml` as an attribute of `mn` ? Is the `__init__.py` file needed to do that or it isn't supported anymore?